# What does the Russian soldier say to Sarah Ross while she is pretending to be a guard in the Kremlin?

Tags: dialogue, translation, red-2

At one point in *Red 2*, the team infiltrates the Kremlin in order to retrieve Nightshade. Sarah Ross (Mary-Louise Parker) has to stand guard outside a door, posing as a security guard. A uniformed man stops to flirt with her, speaking Russian, which she does not speak. She can only reply, "Da". Then she kisses him.

What does the uniformed man (Russian soldier?) say to her? What is the translation of their conversation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to my subtitles this was the dialog.

> Russian soldier: I notice you are still holding up the wall.
>   Sarah Ross: Gas leak. Maintenance is coming.
>   Russian soldier: I'm Pasha. You want to get a drink later?
>   Sarah Ross: Yes?
>   Russian soldier: I thought perhaps you noticed me too!
>   <Sarah kisses him then Frank Moses comes around the corner and knocks him out>

Comment: Thanks! I wonder how he was able to say "I notice you are **still** holding up the wall", and "I thought perhaps you noticed me [earlier] too". How long was she there, and how many times did he walk by?! I thought this sequence only took 5-10 minutes.

Comment: I always understood it as Pasha was in one of the military details that had marched past on their own agenda then snuck off to loop back and introduce himself.

Comment: That would make sense! I'll have to watch that sequence again, and see if I notice him.

Comment: @BrettFromLA Fun fact: Pasha is a name of Persian origin. They also went to Iranian embassy in the movie.